# Connection to cloud server via android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, server, cloud

hope all is well
may anyone please assist me with connecting an android App to a cloud server
for this is my first time doing this and youtube really isn't helpful

any documentations, feedback and links will highly be appreciated

I tried youtube research and expected to get a valid video that would ahow me how to actually show me how to connect to the cloud server and to actually confirm it

THANKS

Comment: You can use Firebase to connect with could. See this [https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/adding-firebase-to-android-app/]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.